# На хостинге использую APP_DEBUG = false , но показывается текст ошибки с дополнительной информацией что делать?

Tags: php, laravel

На хостинге использую *url*  `my-site/1/500` запрос  обрабатывается контроллером, который извлекает данные из базы, но после того как для примера я использую *url*  `/1/5000` выводится ошибка (тат как продукта с номером 5000 нету в базе),

Использую `APP_DEBUG = false`  ошибка показывает информацию в частности

> View: /home/u421655888/domains/changed.ru/resources/views/product-view.blade.php

Безопасно ли такое поведение в laravel,  ведь ошибка показывает скрытую информацию о сайте `/home/u421655888/domains/changed.ru/resources/views/product-view.blade.php` ?

Могут ли злоумышленники использовать эту информацию ?

Должен ли я использовать `try catch` во всех опасных местах (по соображению безопасности) ?

Comment: Безопасность сайта должна быть организована так, чтобы безопасность ни капельки не ослаблялась, даже если выложить исходные коды сайта целиком в открытый доступ. Собственно, многие и выкладывают

Comment: @andreymal но так бывает только в идеальном мире =) в нашем мире баги присутствуют =)

Answer (score 1):

Если с контроллером и маршрутом все норм, то скорее всего, исходя из описания проблемы, закешированы настройки.
Сбросить кеш настроек можно командой `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: после изменения конфигурации  на `APP_DEBUG = false`  изменился  и стиль ошибки (чувствительная информация больше не показывается) ,  вопрос был в том что по умолчанию в этом режиме все-таки показывается информация безопасно ли это (кеш очистил)?

Comment: В режиме `APP_DEBUG=false` в стандартной конфигурации (если не изменял `App\Exceptions\Handler`) выводится очень мало информации https://yadi.sk/i/vKIKFND675ZtCg (эта страница с переведенным сообщением об ошибке). PS: Laravel_5.7

Comment: Да  на  на локальном сервере проверил так и есть значит это делает хостинг,    могу ли изменить поведение хостинга  ?

Comment: кончено, достаточно изменить .env файл и сбросить кеш настроек